# Burning audio CD from .nrg file

Tags: debian, windows, audio-cd

I have audio CD in Nero [.nrg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRG_%28file_format%29) file format (created on Microsoft Windows), and want to burn it on physical Audio CD medium. `nrg2iso(1)` Debian package produces .iso image which doesn't work (nor is it supposed to, according to wikipedia article above, as it is not Data CD).

I've had some luck with `mplayer --cdrom-device=cdimage.nrg cdda://` (it can detect and play audio tracks!) so some support seems to be present (and I could probably kludge it around to extract raw audio), but I'd ideally want to preserve other data (according to `mplayer`, there are at least CD-Text tracks also present)

I'd prefer command-line oriented Debian Jessie package, but I'll take anything that can be compiled/run on Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I try hard to avoid running [non-free](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) software (such as Nero), and I prefered command-line to GUI in this case, I've found other solution.

I installed `libcdio-utils` Debian package, and then used:

```
cd-info cdimage.nrg
```

to get information about `NRG` file which looked sane. Afterwards I used `cd-paranoia` from same package to extract audio tracks as `.wav` files, and then burned them with `wodim` as usual:

```
mkdir wav
cd wav
cd-paranoia -d ../cdrimage.nrg  -B
wodim -v -audio *.wav
```

(note that `cd-paranoia` from `libcdio-utils` package is not the same thing as `cdparanoia` from `cdparanoia` package).

This worked fast and easy for audio (and could be used to RIP audio tracks from `.nrg` image to `mp3` files for example), but `CD-Text` information was lost - I could have used `cd-info` to read `CD-Text` track descriptions and with little scripting record them too back on CD with `wodim -text` (but I was in a hurry and the `CD-Text` info turned out not to be useful in my case...)

Comment: This `libcdio-utils` is based on a buggy and unmaintained old (from 2004) version of cdparanoia. Better use `cdda2wav`, as it fixed the known bugs during the past 15 years and added enhancements to `libparanoia` in order to enhance the extracted audio quality compared to the version of the code from 2004.